# Codeigniter redirect from controller as set in routes config

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I want to redirect the page to the url that is set in routes config.

```
class init extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->helper("url");
    $this->load->model('store');

}

function product($id, $slug=''){

    //if no slug value passed then we obtain the product title and redirect
    if($slug === ''){

        //get the title value from products table and run it through _slugify function
        $slug = $this->_slugify($this->store->read_productTitle($id));

        redirect('init/product/'. $id . '/' . $slug);  //okey when redirect
       // redirect('product/'. $id . '/' . $slug);     redirect loop

    }


}
```

In routes.php

```
 $route['product/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'init/product/$1/$2';
```

When I redirect to `redirect('product/'. $id . '/' . $slug)` then It displayes webpage has redirect loop. How can I solve this without making product controller.

Comment: Have you checked that the $slug in your function is set right? Maybe the value you're storing in $slug is '' again.

Comment: You have a loop. Either code the redirect in your init product method or in the routes, but not both. I personally don't use CI routes and stick with redirect() when I need something redirected.

Comment: Routes don't do HTTP redirects, that's not the problem.

Comment: You could use .htaccess rewrite rules.

Comment: Yes the slug in set successfully.

Comment: How to do from .htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your class code to mine

```
class Init extends CI_Controller //mark first letter uppercase
{

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->helper("url");

}

function product($id, $slug='')
{

    //if no slug value passed then we obtain the product title and redirect
    if($slug === '')
    {        
        $slug = 'hello'; //$this->_slugify($this->store->read_productTitle($id));
        redirect('product/'. $id . '/' . $slug);   
    }
    else
    {
        echo $slug;
    }       
}

}
```

And in routes change

`$route['product/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'init/product/$1/$2';`

Your redirect is ot working because you were redirect on same fuunction from same function :)

Comment: I dont want product1 in url.

Comment: Edited now. This is working fine for me. You have error in **$this->_slugify($this->store->read_productTitle($id));**  check and debug that.. :)